# Write Office Script Formulas containing Quotes

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I am trying to write an Excel office script formula to a cell.  How do I write a formula with quotes to a cell?
This works: wsWa.getCell(WaRangeRowCount, 9).setFormula("= 1 + 1");

How can I write something like this =TEXT($E$18,"dddd").  I am unable to include the quotes using office script.

Comment: Google "Escape quotes" https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/kss/content/kss_adminguide_jscript_escape_characters.htm

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know it was called escape quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you may write strings using three different quote types

```
let single = 'single-quoted';
let double = "double-quoted";

let backticks = `backticks`;
```

So, if you want a string with " just use '-string or `-string

(actually you need to escape " as `\"`  , but what's the point if you can just use another string form)

Check https://javascript.info/string for more info on JS strings